# Pain-free private gems without bundler?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github

I want to distribute a sysadmin utility inside our company that depends on not-yet-released gems (say, the github master for `fog`). We have a private GitHub organization account already, and we all have ssh keys for it.

But: While Bundler can install gems with a simple

```
gem "sysadmin", :git => "git://github.com/ourorg/sysadmin.git"`
```

there's no way I can find to do that with bare RubyGems. And people are going to want to install other gems on their own machine, so I wouldn't want to force everyone to use Bundler for their home directory.

I can think of a few solutions, none ideal:

- Make a "sysadmin" project that has a Gemfile, have everyone clone it, and have them cd into that project dir to run the utility.
- Have them manually download and build the gem on their system every time it changes.
- Use a third-party gem-hosting repo, and count on security-by-obscurity to prevent outsiders from finding it. Ick.
- Set up a secure internal-only server to run `gem server` or the like. We currently don't have one (everything's in the cloud), and I'd like to avoid setting one up just for this.

There must be a better way.. what is it? Is there a way to set up an old-style gem source in a github repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use a third-party gem-hosting repo, and count on security-by-obscurity to prevent outsiders > from finding it. Ick.

I wanted to suggest [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com/), but it sounds like you're not interested in 3rd-party gem-hosting solutions.  Can you tell me more about your security concerns?

*Disclaimer: I work on Gemfury*

Comment: I was thinking about a public gem-hosting repo; I wasn't aware that sites like Gemfury offered authenticated gem repos. That may be the best solution, though there's also something in Bundler 1.1 that may help..

Comment: To which Bundler 1.1 feature are you referring?

Comment: bundler --standalone, which would freeze the gems in place; that's workable for us and free, but I think your solution comes closest to the problem as I expressed it, so I'll accept!

Answer (score -1):

> there's no way I can find to do that with bare RubyGems

This is covered in [the documentation](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html). Use the `:path` option in your Gemfile:

```
gem "nokogiri", :path => "~/sw/gems/nokogiri"
```

And there's no reason this would interfere with their home directory or their own gems. They're not all going to want to put your utilities in their home directory anyway. Let them put the files in whatever directory they want, then either tell them to add it to their `$PATH` or write a Rake task that automatically creates symlinks in e.g. `/usr/bin` for them.

Comment: That's Bundler, not rubygems; there is no Gemfile for bare rubygems - and I would want :git, not :path, since they don't have the git repo locally.